# tf.data.Dataset append element

Tags: tensorflow

Given a TFRecord with the following structure:

```
context_features = {
    "labels_length": tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64),
    "filename": tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
}
sequence_features = {
    "labels": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64)
}
```

I would like to append one element to the `labels` field at run time, when parsing the record file. The iterator written for this dataset also creates batches and pads them with zeros, so it is important to add the element at the end of the list before the padded values are added. For example, if we have three entries: [1.2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9] and the element to be added is 10, the padded batch should look like this:

`[1, 2, 10, 0, 0],
[3, 4, 5, 10, 0],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Could you recommend me a way to do it ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share the existing code that you have to parse the record (presumably using `tf.parse_single_sequence_example()`)? It'll be easiest to explain as an edit to your own code :).

Comment: Sure, here is the code: https://pastebin.com/raw/qC3F0tGt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you can simply use `tf.concat()` to add an element to the `labels` tensor that you get from `tf.parse_single_sequence_example()`. For example, to append `10` to each label:

```
def _parse_labels_function(example):
    context_features = {
        "labels_length": tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64),
        "filename": tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
    }
    sequence_features = {
        "labels": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
        serialized=example,
        context_features=context_features,
        sequence_features=sequence_features
    )

    # Append `10` to each label sequence.
    labels = tf.concat([sequence_parsed["labels"], [10]], 0)

    return labels, context_parsed["labels_length"], context_parsed["filename"]

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(label_record)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_labels_function)
```

Note that I'm not sure how you use the `"labels_length"` feature in your program, but you may also want to add one to it before returning.